# Add formula to copied range

Tags: excel, vba, formula

I'm trying to insert Vlookup Formula in my invoice VBA. The copied range go to the column "A" and I want to insert my formula into the Column"B". Here is where I am right now.

Here is a link to my file: https://drive.google.com/file/d/0By_oZy042nKWSGRNcU14T3g4SXc/edit?usp=sharing

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
    Dim wsInvoice As Worksheet, wsRange As Worksheet

    With ThisWorkbook
        Set wsInvoice = .Worksheets("Invoice")
        Set wsRange = .Worksheets("Range")
        nr = wsInvoice.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row + 1
    End With

    Select Case Me.ComboBox1
        Case "Paper"
            wsRange.Range("Paper").Copy wsInvoice.Cells(nr, 1)
        Case "Pen"
            wsRange.Range("Pen").Copy wsInvoice.Cells(nr, 1)
        Case "Sticker"
            wsRange.Range("Sticker").Copy wsInvoice.Cells(nr, 1)
    End Select
End Sub
```

Comment: Where are you trying to do the Vlookup from? Is that also in wsRange?

Comment: The Copied Range go to Column A. And i want that the formula go to Column B. I can't insert Picture of my sheet so it's hard to explain. But there is 2 Column, Categories And Price.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Right now you have this:

```
    Select Case Me.ComboBox1
        Case "Paper"
            wsRange.Range("Paper").Copy wsInvoice.Cells(nr, 1)
        Case "Pen"
            wsRange.Range("Pen").Copy wsInvoice.Cells(nr, 1)
        Case "Sticker"
            wsRange.Range("Sticker").Copy wsInvoice.Cells(nr, 1)
    End Select
```

To add a Vlookup to it just add `worksheetfunction.vlookup` like this:

```
Select Case Me.ComboBox1
    Case "Paper"
        wsRange.Range("Paper").Copy wsInvoice.Cells(nr, 1)
        wsInvoice.Cells(nr, 2) = Application.WorksheetFunction.VLookup(Cells(nr, 1), wsPrice.Range("A:B"), 2, 0)
    Case "Pen"
        wsRange.Range("Pen").Copy wsInvoice.Cells(nr, 1)
        wsInvoice.Cells(nr, 2) = Application.WorksheetFunction.VLookup(Cells(nr, 1), wsPrice.Range("A:B"), 2, 0)
    Case "Sticker"
        wsRange.Range("Sticker").Copy wsInvoice.Cells(nr, 1)
        wsInvoice.Cells(nr, 2) = Application.WorksheetFunction.VLookup(Cells(nr, 1), wsPrice.Range("A:B"), 2, 0)
End Select
```

I named the arrays, "paperprice", "penprice",etc... and assumed that the prices were in the column directly to the right of the item. It uses the same formula as the regular Vlookup, so it shouldn't be too hard for you to modify to fit to your needs.

Also, add this line where you are setting all the worksheets:

`Set wsPrice = .worksheet("Price")`

EDIT: Thanks for linking to a copy of your workbook.

Try this:

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
Dim wsInvoice As Worksheet, wsRange As Worksheet, wsPrice As Worksheet
Dim nr As Integer, lr As Integer
With ThisWorkbook
    Set wsInvoice = .Worksheets("Invoice")
    Set wsRange = .Worksheets("Range")
    Set wsPrice = .Worksheets("Price")
End With
nr = wsInvoice.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row + 1
Select Case Me.ComboBox1
    Case "Paper"
        wsRange.Range("Paper").Copy wsInvoice.Cells(nr, 1)
        lr = wsInvoice.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
        For i = nr To lr
            wsInvoice.Cells(i, 2) = Application.VLookup(Cells(i, 1), wsPrice.Range("A:B"), 2, 0)
        Next i
    Case "Pen"
        wsRange.Range("B2:B100").Copy wsInvoice.Cells(nr, 1)
        lr = wsInvoice.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
        For i = nr To lr
            wsInvoice.Cells(i, 2) = Application.VLookup(Cells(i, 1), wsPrice.Range("A:B"), 2, 0)
        Next i
    Case "Sticker"
        wsRange.Range("C2:c100").Copy wsInvoice.Cells(nr, 1)
        lr = wsInvoice.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
        For i = nr To lr
            wsInvoice.Cells(i, 2) = Application.VLookup(Cells(i, 1), wsPrice.Range("A:B"), 2, 0)
        Next i
End Select
End Sub
```

NOTE: This will put a #N/A error in the cell if you don't have it in the Price sheet.

Comment: Permanoob it work but it only put data into the upper row. All the other doesn't work. i have a sheet call price that my value are in the column A and the Price is in the column B.

Comment: Just editted. Try it now. I changed it to reference your "Price" sheet.

Comment: Samething it's work but not with multiple data. it only add the price on the upper row.

Comment: @max078 Try it now. Thanks for the link to your workbook. That made it much clearer.

Comment: I've got another Question For you. I'have update my test file Here and i want to add 2 column one percent and another sales price that calculate with the cost and margin. It's work but i want to calculate if i change the percent on my invoice sheet.  https://drive.google.com/file/d/0By_oZy042nKWdTVmX0Fid3JVSHM/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: @Max078 It's probably better to go ahead and make that another question. That way, more people can see it to give you answers. Let me know when you do, and I'll take a crack at it, too.

Comment: Done and Solved! here is a link ! http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20979858/add-a-formula-on-dependant-cell-in-range-using-vba

Answer (score 0):

Let's say you've just copied some value into a cell `MyCell`. Then if you want to put a formula into the next cell to the right you should use this code:

```
MyCell.Offset(0, 1).Formula = "=VLOOKUP(" & MyCell.Address & ",$C:$D,2,false)"
```

Comment: i've tried it but it doesn't work There is a way to post my document ?

Answer (score 0):

```
excelWbk.Sheets(Sheet1).Select
lrow = ActiveSheet.Range("A65536").End(xlUp).Row

excelWbk.Sheets(Sheet11).Select
lrow_sheet2 = ActiveSheet.Range("A65536").End(xlUp).Row


excelWbk.Sheets(Sheet1).Select
With excelWbk.ActiveSheet
For i = 2 To lrow

.Cells(i, 3).Formula = "=VLOOKUP(A" & i & ",Sheet11!$A$1:$B$" & lrow_sheet2 & ",2,0)"

        Next i
End With


With excelWbk.ActiveSheet
    .Range("C" & lrow).Select
Selection.Copy
    Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks _
        :=False, Transpose:=False
  End With
```