# Add a formula on dependant cell in range using vba

Tags: vba, excel

I want to insert a calculation on a cell using VBA. Here is how i insert it right now. it's work pretty Good but i cannot mod the percent on the invoice sheet. I want that after i insert the row i can modify the percent and it will update automatically the selling price.

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
Dim wsInvoice As Worksheet, wsRange As Worksheet, wsPrice As Worksheet
Dim nr As Integer, lr As Integer
With ThisWorkbook
     Set wsInvoice = .Worksheets("Invoice")
     Set wsRange = .Worksheets("Range")
     Set wsPrice = .Worksheets("Price")
 End With
nr = wsInvoice.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row + 1
Select Case Me.ComboBox1
Case "Paper"
    wsRange.Range("Paper").Copy wsInvoice.Cells(nr, 1)
    lr = wsInvoice.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
    For i = nr To lr
        wsInvoice.Cells(i, 2) = Application.VLookup(Cells(i, 1), wsPrice.Range("A:B"), 2, 0)
        wsInvoice.Cells(i, 3) = (".3")
        wsInvoice.Cells(i, 4).Formula = FormatCurrency(wsInvoice.Cells(i, 2).Value / (1 - (wsInvoice.Cells(i, 3))), 2, vbFalse, vbFalse, vbTrue)
    Next i
```

Here is a link to download my document.
https://drive.google.com/file/d/0By_oZy042nKWdTVmX0Fid3JVSHM/edit?usp=sharing

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the FormatCurrency here is a bit useless, this can be accomplished by formatting the column once and leaving it like that. There seems to be an issue with the Formula and FormulaLocal inside form functions. Here's my fix :

Remove the lines  `wsInvoice.Cells(i,4).Formula ...`

At the end of the CommandButton1_Click(), add this line  `FormulaCorrection`

Inside a module, write down this very simple function that shall do what you want :

```
Sub FormulaCorrection()

    Sheets("Invoice").Activate
    lastRow = Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
    For x = 2 To lastRow
        Cells(x, 4).FormulaLocal = "=B" & x & "/(1-C" & x & ")"
    Next x

End Sub
```

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what you mean.

Comment: If you're having trouble implementing my solution I can give some more instructions. This, however, really should solve your problem.

Comment: Very glad I could help!

Answer (score 1):

If I understand you correctly, here is one way:

Modify this line:

```
wsInvoice.Cells(i, 4).Formula = FormatCurrency(wsInvoice.Cells(i, 2).Value / (1 - (wsInvoice.Cells(i, 3))), 2, vbFalse, vbFalse, vbTrue)
```

to be:

```
wsInvoice.Cells(i, 4).Formula = "=" & wsInvoice.Cells(i, 2).Value & "/ (1 - (C" & i & "))"
```

That seemed to work on my test sheet at least.

Edit:

Also, your whole method can be condensed a bit.  This should do the same thing:

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
Dim wsInvoice As Worksheet, wsRange As Worksheet, wsPrice As Worksheet
Dim nr As Integer, lr As Integer
With ThisWorkbook
    Set wsInvoice = .Worksheets("Invoice")
    Set wsRange = .Worksheets("Range")
    Set wsPrice = .Worksheets("Price")
End With
nr = wsInvoice.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row + 1
Select Case Me.ComboBox1
    Case "Paper"
        wsRange.Range("Paper").Copy wsInvoice.Cells(nr, 1)
    Case "Pen"
        wsRange.Range("B2:B100").Copy wsInvoice.Cells(nr, 1)
    Case "Sticker"
        wsRange.Range("C2:c100").Copy wsInvoice.Cells(nr, 1)
End Select

        lr = wsInvoice.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
        For i = nr To lr
            wsInvoice.Cells(i, 2) = Application.VLookup(Cells(i, 1), wsPrice.Range("A:B"), 2, 0)
            wsInvoice.Cells(i, 3) = (".3")
            wsInvoice.Cells(i, 4).Formula = "=" & wsInvoice.Cells(i, 2).Value & "/ (1 - (C" & i & "))"
        Next i
End Sub
```

Comment: @Max078 That's odd, it works fine on my end when I replace the entire method with the one I added in my Edit.  I'm able to add any of the combo box items and it populates down the sheet.  Can you tell me what the error is?

Comment: @Max078 can you post the workbook that's giving you the error back to your google drive and repost the link?  I don't get any errors on my end.

Comment: sorry, I'm still at a loss as when I run the code on the sheet you just posted, I'm not getting any error.

Comment: It's work i've found the problem but i'm not able to resolve it. It's working only in full number exemple: 12.00 but it doesn't work with 12.37 !

Comment: Glad you got it working! Unfortunately, I can't reproduce any errors.  It works fine with whole numbers as well as numbers out to two decimal places.